# Solr Indexing XML strategies. Save all XML as a field vs pre process XML before save

Tags: java, xml, solr, lucene

Good Afternoon.

I'm pretty new in Sorl. I need index a lot of XML files from WS comunication request/response and more generic information like a "template", that template have by example the service invoked, operation, time consumed and so on.

I maked a a few test with indexs in Solr and I advertise two strategies for index all this data. One solution will be save all the XML of the request and the response, in two fields of the document in the index of Solr.
The other one will be make a transformation of the request and the response, and extract the data that will be important for Us, and populate the index with that info in a few fields of interest.

I will put a small example of the first alternative, **Save all XML as a field**

*Index Schema*

```
<!-- Service Template data!-->
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/> 
   <field name="service" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="version" type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="operation" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="server" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="invocationTime" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="appName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="userName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="dateHour" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="error" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="businessFault" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="request" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/> <!-- here will save all the XML body of the request -->
   <field name="response" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/> <!-- here will save all the XML body of the response -->
```

*Index Data*

```
<doc>
    <!-- Service Template data-->
    <field name="id">ID:10.250.2.31-1456089599e-12:13722</field>
    <field name="service">SocioUnificado</field>
    <field name="version">v1</field>
    <field name="operation">getSocioCompleto</field>
    <field name="server">testesb.osde.ar</field>
    <field name="url">http://testesb.osde.ar/ESB/jbi/Socio/</field>
    <field name="invocationTime">450</field>
    <field name="appName">ESB_SUPPORT</field>
    <field name="userName">FLUX</field>
    <field name="dateHour">2014-04-11T08:45:56Z</field>
    <field name="error">false</field>
    <field name="businessFault">false</field>
    <field name="request"><![CDATA[<getXX>
         <dataFilter>
            <date>20120813</date>
            <contractNumber>234</contractNumber>
            <orderNumber>01</orderNumber>
         </dataFilter>
      </dataFilter>]]></field>
    <field name="response"><![CDATA[<getXXResponse>
         <client>
            <contract>
               <attentionCenterInfo>
                  <code>11</code>
                  <description>CALIFORNIA LA</description>
                  <buildingInfo>
                     <code>35</code>
                     <description>BIG BUILDING 2</description>
                  </buildingInfo>
               </attentionCenterInfo>
    ... And a lot of more XML DATA ... ]]>
  </doc>
```

The second alternative **pre process XML before save**

*Index Schema*

```
   <!-- Service Template data!-->
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/> 
   <field name="service" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="version" type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="operation" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="server" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="invocationTime" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="appName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="userName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="dateHour" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="error" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="businessFault" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <!-- Service particular data -->
   <field name="contractNumber" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="orderNumber" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="date" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

*Index Data*

```
 <doc>
    <!-- Service Template data-->
    <field name="id">ID:10</field>
    <field name="service">service1</field>
    <field name="version">v1</field>
    <field name="operation">getXX</field>
    <field name="server">server1</field>
    <field name="url">http://server1/ESB/service1/</field>
    <field name="invocationTime">450</field>
    <field name="appName">ESB_SUPPORT</field>
    <field name="userName">ODOR</field>
    <field name="dateHour">2014-04-11T08:45:56Z</field>
    <field name="error">false</field>
    <field name="businessFault">false</field>
    <!-- Service particular data -->
    <field name="date">20120813</field>
    <field name="contractNumber">610</field>
    <field name="orderNumber">01</field>
  </doc>
```

I whant know what are yours opinion about this strategies? and if you know another that fit better in this use case?

I can say that the data of a request/response of ours service can be pretty long (like 120 lines of XML in avg), and we have in global more than 300 services. We have services that are consumed in production 80.000 request per day. Finally, I can say that all information in the request/response have diferent structure for each operation of each service (all heterogenuos data).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you need run different solr instances in maybe different machines to index each xml file.

Comment: Thanks for reponse @Hector, i don't know if i was clear in the questions. But, i need a way of save XML data in Solr. If We have a problem of performance later, maybe yes make many clustered instances of Solr help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only indexing one XML file, so, is for this reason that I suggest you have many clustered instances of solr, each one for each xml file.

Comment: I get the point, you said create and index of Solr per service operation (XML of request/response). That is an option follow the strategy **pre process XML before save** i think. But i need more info about the two options, or a more eficient strategy as well. Thanks